# If I design a lego set

Tags: design

If I design a Lego set that you may be interested in selling, whom do I contact in the company?

My husband iis constantly building new buildings etc. Thought your company may be interested.

Comment: Note: Lego Answers is not affiliated with The Lego Group. We are a fan site, answering your questions.

Answer (score 4):

Lego has a website called [Lego Ideas](http://ideas.lego.com/) through which fans can submit set ideas. Other fans vote on their favorite projects, and if a project receives 10,000 votes, Lego will consider making the set into an official release.

[image: Lego Ideas Logo]